# Oracle: Match an expression and if expression is null, return all records fro that column

Tags: php, sql, oracle

i have a search form where a user can search for certain fields in the database. if a field is left empty it can match anything including null. If something is entered in the field, it should match to that field including wildcards.

I'm using php as server-side language.

The issue is, if a search field is empty, I can't just use php and convert it to '%' as it will not match null. (assuming where clause is fieldA like $value). Also I can't use "fieldA like $value OR fieldA IS NULL" because then it will return all matching fields and fields that are null.

Is there a (rather simple way) to to this in an SQL Statement? Currently I build the where clause in PHP and it is rather cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempted solution is checking the wrong item for nullability.

You need a record to always yield TRUE if the parameter is NULL, or TRUE if the field matches the parameter...

```
WHERE
  fieldA LIKE $value
  OR $value IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

> if a field is left empty it can match anything including null

Well, why not just leave out the where clause all together in this case?

```
case 1: user enters "ABC"

select * from my_table where fieldA like 'ABC%';

case 2: user leaves blank

select * from my_table;
```

BTW, be careful of SQL injection.